# SQL replace cte by actual table to improve performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table `#temp` has an index on `(NrBL, LgnBL)`. But in SQL Server 2016, common table expressions cannot be indexed. Could it be faster to use another temporary table instead of the CTE, and index it on `(NrBL, LgnBL)` ?

```
WITH cte (NrBL, LgnBL, clientNr) AS 
(
    SELECT NrBL, LgnBL, clientNr
    FROM #temp
    WHERE Niveau=0
)
UPDATE a
SET a.ClientNr = cte.ClientNr
FROM #temp AS a
JOIN cte ON a.NrBL=cte.NrBL AND a.LgnBL = cte.LgnBL;
```

Comment: A CTE isn't an table, it's an expression; of course it can't be indexed. If you're using a CTE you need to ensure the underlying tables referenced in the CTE is index. In this case that would appear to be the columns `NrBL` and `LgnBL` with an `INCLUDE` on `ClientNr`. On a different note [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an updatable CTE with window functions is the best approach:

```
WITH cte (NrBL, LgnBL, clientNr) AS (
      SELECT t.*,
             MAX(CASE WHEN Niveau = 0 THEN clientNr END) OVER (PARTITION BY NrBL, LgnBL) as new_clientNr
      FROM #temp t
     )
UPDATE cte
    SET ClientNr = new_ClientNr
    WHERE new_clientNR IS NOT NULL;
```

You can create an index on `(NrBL, LgnBL, Niveau, clientNr)`.

Comment: UPDATE cte, not t.

Comment: Now if #temp has 60 columns, can I pull just NrBL, LgnBL, clientNr ? Could it be faster ? Otherwise, it works, but the performance gain is not stellar, if any.

Comment: @user3046585 . . . Have you added the recommended index?  Limiting the number of columns in the CTE doesn't matter -- the SQL optimizer takes care of that.

Comment: There is an index on (NrBL, LgnBL, Niveau, IdLot). It is more reusable so, as this query is not alone. Is covering clientNr unavoidable ?

Comment: @LudovicAubert . . . Including it in the index might help.  You need to look at the execution plan to see if the index is being used for the `max()` calculation.

Comment: Execution plan does not mention max() directly. It tells 85% cost during clustered index update on query exit. The table has a column (id integer primary key identity). I am assuming it gets included in the index without saying...Anyway, the update hits most rows, but it should be really fast, and isn't

Comment: @LudovicAubert . . . Updating all rows in a table is going to be slow because of all the logging required.  It is often faster to generate the data in a new table, truncate the original table and reload it.

Comment: Updating all rows in my table is indeed slow. I wasn't aware of this logging required. Could you develop ? Another thing I noticed is that multicolumn update is faster than multiple single column update. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56893390/lots-of-updates-to-a-large-table-how-to-speed-up

Comment: @LudovicAubert . . . Not to the best of my knowledge.  You can change the recovery mode to "simple".  That doesn't stop the logging though.  It simple recovers the space used immediately.

Answer (score 1):

It *might* help to use a temp table (the query optimizer can surprise you, sometimes), but I find it more likely the temp table will make things **worse**.

It is correct you can't index a CTE... but *that does not mean indexes will not be used for the query*. There are still indexes on the source tables from the CTE, and those indexes can still be helpful for your full query.  With a temp table you definitely have to both populate the full table and the index(es).