# Lots of updates to a large table. How to speed up?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a large table (60 columns, 2 million rows).

It is built by first a recursive query, and then most columns get updated in their own way.
All this updating is quite slow (80% of global duration).

The order of the updates cannot be completely random as some columns serve as input for the computation of other columns. But the order is free to some extent.

Is it common practice to replace a list of UPDATE by a large  SELECT CASE ? Currently I have something like this:

```
UPDATE t SET col1=col2/col3 WHERE col4 IS NULL AND col5 IS NOT NULL; --UPDATE Nr1

UPDATE t SET col23=col24+col25 WHERE col26 IS NULL; --UPDATE Nr2

...

UPDATE t SET col46=col47*col48 WHERE col1 IS NULL --UPDATE Nr50
```

Could it be replaced by something like:

```
CREATE TABLE t2 AS
SELECT
CASE WHEN col4 IS NULL AND col5 IS NOT NULL THEN col2/col3 ELSE col1 END AS col1,
...
CASE WHEN col26 IS NULL THEN col24+col25 ELSE col23 END AS col23,
..
FROM t;

CREATE TABLE t3 AS
SELECT
col1,
col2,...,
CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN col47*col48 ELSE col46 END AS col46
FROM t2;
```

Comment: `"How to speed up?"` By posting table structure, sample data and update logic.Providing https://dbfiddle.uk demo and desired result would help a lot

Comment: Can you provide a simplified example of what you are actually asking?

Comment: Have a look at "computed columns":  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: It sounds like the schema design needs to be rethought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--Requete 40. Performance cost: 3%
UPDATE #temp_arbo_of_3
SET PxAchat=NULL, CuTpsAch=NULL
WHERE IdBE IS NULL;


--Requete 41. Performance cost: 2%
UPDATE #temp_arbo_of_3
SET CuTrait = NULL
WHERE IdBE IS NOT NULL;


--Requete 42. Performance cost: 2%
UPDATE #temp_arbo_of_3
SET NrOF_Source = _ofI
WHERE IdBE IS NOT NULL;
```

Now if I replace all this by:

```
--Requete 40. Performance cost: 3%
UPDATE #temp_arbo_of_3
SET PxAchat=CASE WHEN IdBE IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE PxAchat END,
     CuTpsAch=CASE WHEN IdBE IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CuTpsAch END,
     CuTrait=CASE WHEN IdBE IS NOT NULL THEN NULL ELSE CuTrait END,
     NrOF_Source=CASE WHEN IdBE IS NOT NULL THEN _ofI ELSE NrOF_source END
WHERE IdBE IS NULL;
```

Performance (as indicated by SQL Server execution plan) is better. 3%+2%+2% > 3%

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it's a bit hard for me to understand what is the aim. If You are calculating something big from all columns maybe You could use some big stored procedure all the calculations and maybe that way You will be able to decrease the number of updates.

Anyway.. also since speed is the parameter You are looking for and not the amount of space, then did You consider indexing? If You have lots of updates You can consider nonclustered index, this for sure always 'speed up' :).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-2017